# What's the purpose of inverted bombing on this building?

Tags: tenet

Ives and the Protagonist shelter as the Red team exchanges fire with the Enemy further up the street. The Protagonist checks his watch: "5:15, 5:14............"

> **Protagonist:** We're runnin' out of time, let's go!
>
> **Ives:** If they see us, it's all for nothing.
>
> **Protagonist:** We need a distraction.

[image: animated GIF of the described scene]

What's the purpose of inverted bombing on this building?

Comment: Looks pretty distracting to me

Comment: You have answered your question . It was a distraction wasn't it?

Comment: Looks for me just like atoms of the building perform as "normal" and "inverted" at the same time.

Comment: When you are in the upper floor, you first un-die and then you get your ass shot out from underneath you. But why is there a multi-storey building in the middle of nowhere?

Comment: The question presupposes that Tenet was in any way coherent or meaningful. Since the question is based on a false assumption, the only possible answer is mu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)

Comment: That clip seems to show the top of the building getting blown up in one shot, then another shot showing the top getting "healed" while the bottom is destroyed--is one shot meant to be from the perspective of an inverted observer, and the other from the perspective of a non-inverted observer? And if not, does that mean the top was initially intact, then got blown up, then immediately got hit by an inverted missile that "healed" it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rockets are both fired at the midpoint of the battle (at exactly 5 minutes) - so the undestruction/destruction of the tower is almost certainly a coordinated event between the red and blue teams designed to cause the distraction that was just called for.